# How to empty an object (object fields can be vary and dynamic)

Tags: javascript

How to reset the object as below.
As a static object, I can use the below one but, have this object can contain additional fields or less fields then below as its dynamically provided.
How to make empty this object as below.

```
var object={
    id:0,
    clientId:0,
    position:'',
    positionCnt:'',
    InsValue:'',
        Code:'',
        FieldName:''
};
```

Comment: You could define some defaults by type (`{string: '', number:0, ...}`) and use a combination of reflection/recursion and `typeof` to create a stripped version of an existing object. Although I'd suggest giving it a go of your own before asking us to :)

Comment: `object = {}` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms — That would overwrite the `object` variable, not change the existing object.

Comment: @JonasWilms I believe the "empty" object *is* the one he provided. As in, set all the numbers to `0`, strings to `''`, etc. I may be misunderstanding that myself though.

Comment: I removed the term JSON from your question, but you keep using it in comments. [Your question has nothing to do with JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: What about nested objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set an object that defines the default values by type (`string`, `number`, etc).

With this defined, the below would loop through the object and set the property values to their type-defaults.

**Important:** The code below is a solid start but it doesn't handle `arrays`, nested objects, etc, so you'll have to flesh it out a bit.

```js
var defaultTypeValues = {
  number: 0,
  string: '',
  boolean: false
};

var obj = {
  id: 525,
  clientId: 1624,
  position: 'pos',
  positionCnt: 'abc',
  InsValue: 'def',
  Code: 'abc123',
  FieldName: 'fieldname'
}

function emptyObj(obj, defaultOverrides = {}) {
  var defaults = Object.assign({}, defaultTypeValues, defaultOverrides);
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => obj[k] = defaults[typeof obj[k]]);
  return obj;
}

console.log(emptyObj(obj));
```

I've added a second (optional) parameter  `defaultOverrides`, where you can specify values to override the defaults, ie, `emptyObj(obj, {boolean: true});` would replace all bool values with `true` instead of the default `false`.

Comment: this works for me. this is what need. Thanks, I can extend this to additional data type too.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = {one: 1, two: '2', three: 3, four: true}

let sort = (obj, val, val2, val3) => { 
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(x => {
    if (typeof obj[x] === 'string') {
       obj[x] = val;
    } else if (typeof obj[x] === 'number') {
       obj[x] = val2;
    } else if (typeof obj[x] === 'boolean') {
       obj[x] = val3;
    }  else { 
       // Extend here to datatypes
    }
  });
}
let set = obj => sort(obj, '', 0, false); // Additional types

set(a)
console.log('After:', a)
```

Comment: here, JSON property is not known and its dynamic. It can contains three types of properties, string, number and boolean . If string then to reset as '', boolean then false and number then 0

Answer (score 0):

Keep a template object so you know what you want to reset it to.

Then loop over and erase all the properties, and assign the template over it.

```js
const template = {
  id: 0,
  clientId: 0,
  position: '',
  positionCnt: '',
  InsValue: '',
  Code: '',
  FieldName: ''
};

let object = {
  id: 0,
  //  clientId: 0,
  //  position: '',
  positionCnt: '',
  InsValue: '',
  Code: '',
  FieldName: 'with a different value',
  extraField: "Hello, world"
};

console.log("Before", JSON.stringify(object, null, 2));

Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
  delete object[key];
});

Object.assign(object, template);

console.log("After", JSON.stringify(object, null, 2));
```

Comment: The only issue I see here is that it sounds like the fields are not known ahead of time.

Comment: @TylerRoper — I interpreted the question to mean that the object could vary but the template was fixed. I can see how it could be interpreted another way though. It isn't very clear.

Comment: Understood, and agreed. Kinda taking shots in the dark unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign`

```
let newObject = Object.assign(object, {position: "x"});
```

```js
var object={
    id:0,
    clientId:0,
    position:'',
    positionCnt:'',
    InsValue:'',
        Code:'',
        FieldName:''
};
let newObject = Object.assign(object, {position: "x"});
console.log(newObject);
```

Or the spread operator `...obj`

```
    let newObject = { ...object, position: "x"};
```

```js
var object = {
  id: 0,
  clientId: 0,
  position: '',
  positionCnt: '',
  InsValue: '',
  Code: '',
  FieldName: ''
};

let newObject = { ...object,
  position: "x"
};

console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: here, JSON property is not known and its dynamic. It can contains three types of properties, string, number and boolean . If string then to reset  as `''`, boolean then `false` and number then `0`

Comment: @user3711357 I strongly suggest that you add the above clarification to your question.

Comment: @user3711357 Ah - I presumed you were sanitizing the object elsewhere before creating a new one. I would definitely add that to the original question text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of working prototype with nested objects.
It doesn't use variables out of the scope, easily testable and maintainable.

```js
const toDefault = defaults => {
  return function resetter(o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(key => {
      if (typeof o[key] === "object") {
        o[key] = resetter(o[key]);
      } else {
        o[key] = defaults[typeof o[key]];
      }
    })
    
    return o;
  }
}

const reset = toDefault({string: "", number: -1});

var obj = {
    id: 1230,
    clientId:0,
    position:'',
    positionCnt:'',
    InsValue:'',
    Code:'12312312',
    FieldName:'',
        
    nested: {
      a:12312,
      b:123123
    }
};

console.log(reset(obj));
```